# Table with Unique Clustered Index and an Indexed View are stored in same way. What is the benefit of Indexed View then?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Table with Unique Clustered Index and an Indexed View are stored in same way. What is the benefit of Indexed View then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An indexed view is useful for

- precalculaion eg aggregates
- pre-JOINing
- pre-filtering eg all active products

If you have an indexed view on a single table that returns all rows, all columns there is no point

There is a whitepaper ["Improving Performance with SQL Server 2005 Indexed Views"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx) worth reading

Answer (score 1):

If it is just storing the raw table values absolutely nothing. The main benefit comes from indexed views containing aggregates. These can be retrieved directly instead of recalculating the aggregate from the base data every time which can dramatically reduce I/O.

Comment: But in the normal case of when we build views without index, if we insert data into the column the view is not updated, it is run only when quried. In this case of indexed view, when we insert data into the table, i think the view will be rebuild, because clustered index will be rebuild(same in the case of table with clustered index).

Comment: @Puneet - When the underlying table data changes the values stored in the View index(es) of course need to be updated (this is done automatically by SQL Server). There are quite a few restrictions on indexed views presumably to try and avoid constructs that would make this very expensive.